# Wordpress not loading scripts for plugin at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

So I have the action for loading my scripts in my plugin as so.

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'loadAssets' ) );
```

And the corresponding function set as so:

```
public function loadAssets() {
        // add stylesheet to all pages
        wp_enqueue_style(
                'styles', // handle
                plugins_url( 'styles/main.css', __FILE__ ), // src for js                
                array(),
                WP_DEBUG ? time() : $this->version // version, null removes version, false uses wordpress version
                );

        wp_register_script( 'jquery.ezmark.min', // handle
                plugins_url( 'js/jquery.ezmark.min.js', __FILE__ ), // src for js
                array( 'jquery' ), // dependancies
                WP_DEBUG ? null : $this->version, // version, null removes version, false uses wordpress version
                true
                );
}
```

Now the main.css load in perfectly fine but no matter what I do the Javascript files do not load at all.

They where working perfectly fine yesterday and now when I loaded the site they stopped working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To include CSS and jQuery in your plugin is easy, try this:

```
// register jquery and style on initialization
add_action('init', 'register_script');
function register_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom_jquery', plugins_url('/js/custom-jquery.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );

    wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url('/css/new-style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
}

// use the registered jquery and style above
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');

function enqueue_style(){
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_jquery');
   wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this ,

```
add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'loadAssets' ) );
```

to this,

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'loadAssets' ) );
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that and it didn't work unfortunately.